# Can't read/write to properties of an Objective-C class from within a CGPDFOperator C function

Tags: objective-c, c, cgpdfdocument, pdf-parsing

OK, so I'm using C callback functions being run from a `CGPDFScanner`. These functions are within a class called `PDFContentStreamProcessor` with an `NSMutableArray` property called `myArray`

ARC is enabled, but I made an exception in the build phases for this class.

```
void RandomCallbackOperatorFunction(CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {
    PDFContentStreamProcessor * searcher = (PDFContentStreamProcessor*)info;
    [searcher setMyArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aString",@"AnotherString", nil]];
    NSLog(@"arraylength:%i",searcher.myArray.count);
}
```

It finds text, integers and objects just fine, but I can't do much with the values if I can't store them anywhere.  Any ideas?

I've also tried it this way:

```
[(PDFContentStreamProcessor*)info setMyArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aString",@"AnotherString", nil]];
```

... also with no luck

Comment: You're not clear on the issue. Have you verified that `searcher` isn't `nil` when this function is called?

Comment: It is nil! Now I have a different problem... Thanks for pointing that out.